# Replace characters within an msbuild variable

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I need to replace characters in a variable I am passing to an exec task within msbuild 4. Specifically, I need to replace all occurrences of backslashes `\` with forward-slashes `/` in the `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` variable.

eg:

```
<Target Name="DoStuff">
    <Exec Command="stuff.exe $(MSBuildProjectDirectoryWithSlashesFixed)/SomeFile.txt" />
</Target>
```

The executable being called is an oracle component that can't deal with slashes in windows format.

I've had a look at [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx), but as `System.String.Replace()` is an instance method rather than a static method, it seems it can't be used for my needs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can also use instance methods as property functions (as long as you restrict yourself to types registered as safe).

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildProjectDirectoryWSF>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory.Replace('\', '/'))</MSBuildProjectDirectoryWSF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(I might have missed some escaping on the slashes).

More documentation is available on [Visual Studio Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-property-functions/).