# How to escape backslash in $(SolutionDir) in a VS project file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to write a post-build event for a C# project. And I'm using a custom console app (`myTool.exe`) to do that.

For example, the post-build event is

> "$(SolutionDir)tools\myTool.exe" "$(SolutionDir)myProject\bin\" Debug

(All paths is quoted because they could contain whitespaces.)

Before escaping, `$(SolutionDir)` is `D:\Some\MySystem\`.
After escaping, it should become `D:\\Some\\MySystem\\`.

How to escape all the `\` in `$(SolutionDir)` in this way in a csproj file?

I have tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6467010/3427520), but it seems not working for `$(SolutionDir)`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EscapedSolutionDir>$(SolutionDir.Replace('\\', '\\\\'))</EscapedSolutionDir>
  <EscapedTargetDir>$(TargetDir.Replace('\\', '\\\\'))</EscapedTargetDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(EscapedSolutionDir)source\\Native\\Output\\NativeLibraryCopier.exe&quot; &quot;$(EscapedSolutionDir)&quot; &quot;$(ConfigurationName)&quot; &quot;$(PlatformName)&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

PS: See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/) for why I have to replace the backslash.

Comment: Why does it need to be escape, am i missing something?

Comment: You should Replace '\' with "\\"? As per my understanding escape is not the correct word here. Also please post code, you tried using the example.

Comment: Joining @Saruman 's question: why does MyTool.exe need to get this argument with double-back-slashes? Isn't it easier to do such string operations inside MyTool.exe?

Comment: @felix-b Because I need the variable like `$(SolutionDir)` and `` provided by Visual Studio. It is not a fixed value and `$(TargetDir)` will be passed as an argument.

Comment: AFAIK there should be no problem passing $(SolutionDir) as is in an argument to your tool. Have you tried passing it as is?

Comment: @felix-b I need to use mytool.exe in the post-build event.

Comment: Obviously, my question was why do you think that escaping is necessary at all? Is MyTool.exe a program that you wrote? If yes, in this program try printing the value of the first argument -- isn't it OK without escaping? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @felix-b  Number of argments got inside mytoo.exe is incorrect. There should be four but there is only one(the entire line).

Answer (score 2):

> How to escape backslash in $(SolutionDir) in a VS project file?

Not sure why you want to replace the "\" with "\\" in the $(SolutionDir). That because this property is [common macros for build commands and properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx), **You can use these macros anywhere in a project's Property Pages dialog box where strings are accepted**.

But if you insist on replacing it, you should replace it with `$(SolutionDir.Replace('\', '\\'))` rather than `$(SolutionDir.Replace('\\', '\\\\'))`. Because the path in the `$(SolutionDir)` is `D:\Some\MySystem\`, **Only one backslash**. When you replace it with double backslashes, MSBuild could not find the double backslashes in the `$(SolutionDir)`.

So the scripts should be:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EscapedSolutionDir>$(SolutionDir.Replace('\', '\\'))</EscapedSolutionDir>
    <EscapedTargetDir>$(TargetDir.Replace('\', '\\'))</EscapedTargetDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then I use a target to output the escaped value in the `EscapedSolutionDir` and `EscapedTargetDir`, both those value were escaped:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="$(EscapedSolutionDir)" Importance="high">
    </Message>
    <Message Text="$(EscapedTargetDir)" Importance="high">
    </Message>
  </Target>
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: I have already tried what you typed and it also doesn't work. Let's discuss about it later. I'm a little busy now.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Upvoted. I'll try that later.

Comment: @zwcloud, It does not matter. You can reply me when you free. I output the escaped value, found it was changed to "\\", you can check your escaped value with this method. If you find it already changed to "\\", you problem may not about change "\" to "\\", it may be for other reasons that you can not run your tool.exe.

Comment: It doesn't work on the second variable `$(EscapedTargetDir)`. I mean the second message wasn't printed in the output window. I have lost my confidence in MSBuild. I will parse [`commandline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline) myself.

Comment: [This is why I want to escape the backslash.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/)

Comment: @zwcloud, if the `$(SolutionDir)` works fine but `$(EscapedTargetDir)`, you can use `$(SolutionDir)`$(ProjectName)\\bin\\Debug\\ replace.

Comment: I mean I didn't see the second red-underlined message.

Comment: @zwcloud, yes, I know. What is your test target in your project? Have you set the test line `<Message Text="$(EscapedTargetDir)" Importance="high">
    </Message>`? If yes, what is the output log?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some Environ Vars finish with a backslash....
add a "." and then when using them add the "\"
for example I was trying to get a meesage (#pragma message) with a file path and name...

I did it like this:
<PreprocessorDefinitions>INT_DIR=$(IntDir.Replace('', '\')).;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>

And then

#define MyFile "File.ext"

#pragma message ( TO_STR(INT_DIR) "\\" MyFile "(0) : MESSAGE: File Included")